# How to add 2d styled brush effect to 3d model?

Tags: compositing-nodes

[image]

This is a 3d rock model, I compost it with a 2d background.

[image]

[image]

I want to ask is there any way to add some 2d styled brush texture to this rock? Not too much, just a little bit to make the rock fit the background.

Comment: What do you mean by "2d styled brush texture"? Something like a toon shader for the rock so the style of the rock matches the background?

Comment: like oil painting